# How to remove the seam?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology, seams

I want to remove this seam around the mouth. I don't know why this happened and i can't fix it. I've tried to remake topology but, the seam just changes position.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you may have inverted normals in that section - try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then press Shift+N (recalculate normals outside).

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: also make sure you don't have overlapping vertices, select all and press M > Merge by Distance